# Change keyboard layout on mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

I'm on macOS Sierra and I would like to know how to change my keyboard layout from the command line, so I can automate tasks  with python using PyAutoGui.

Is there a specific command or do I need a script? I'm using a Qwertz Swiss keyboard. So a simple example of my problem is that if I don't change my keyboard to Qwerty manually, I get **mz** and not **my**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the tool below:

https://github.com/vovkasm/input-source-switcher

The tool is used to switch the input method when using vim. An example of usage can be found below:

https://github.com/xream/atom-vim-mode-plus-auto-ime